# Why didn't Harry Dresden try to know more about his mother?

Tags: the-dresden-files

I was reading Blood Rites when I came to a passage where

> Thomas told Harry that they share a mother.

And he was really surprised. Earlier in the series, I have seen him call up some demon and asking questions about another person (Fool Moon), then why didn't he try to find more about his own mother?

Comment: Is that bit in blue supposed to be spoiler? Not read the books myself so wouldn't know, but if so it's visible :)

Comment: @maccooper - Sorted.

Comment: It's been a while since I read Fool Moon, but wasn't Harry _tempted_ to ask the demon about his mother when it offered, but he refused to pay the price (another portion of his True Name)?

Comment: Also, it's been some time since I read Blood Rites, but doesn't the book go into more details about Harry's mother (after the spoilered event takes place)?

Comment: My guess is that he did try doing research on his mother, but certain parties with knowledge and power were uncooperative and actively hiding things.  There are pretty significant things that are not revealed until 'Changes'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He may have tried; we don't get to see all his activities in the roughly year-long gap between books.  That said, every source that might have known something about his mother was, at that point in the series, either hostile to him or unknown to him.

Lets go down a list:

- The Spirit Realm.  Chaunzaggoroth ("Chauncy") is the underworld spirit who offered information on his mother Margaret, but only to bait Harry into giving up his Name, after lulling him into false confidence by playing the harmless broker demon card.  Harry might have a few other demonic sources of info, but they're all in the same ballpark as Chauncy; too risky to deal with.  Almost losing his Name put Harry off of summoning for a while; we don't see him call on the spirit realm again until Death Masks, at great need and in unknown waters, and even then he's dealing with a loa, not the underworld again.
- His father's dead, and as far as he knows that was his only family.  No one else to ask who would obviously know.
- Thomas.  He knows, and is hanging around Harry watching his back, but other than this odd, brief, and questionable companionship never gives any indication of their connection.  When Harry finally calls him on it is what prompts his revelation, and is the moment that fuels your question.
- The Fae.  Lea knows and could tell him a bunch, but Harry spends most of two books trying to work out of his already considerable debts with her, and fails.  Mab has him on speed dial, and one favor to her was enough to kill him.  Asking either would just dig him deeper.  He isn't desperate enough to do that until Dead Beat, and then what he's asking is directly related to Fae.
- The Wardens of the White Council.  Doubtless they have extensive files on Margaret LeFey as they knew her, but he wouldn't know that.  They also bear a grudge against Harry, thinking him just a warlock who's gotten lucky with technicalities, and with Morgan to light that grudge into a bonfire.  He's staying off their radar.
- His other White Council contacts, namely McCoy.  I'm not sure Harry even knows Margaret was on the Council at this point, just that his magic comes from her.  By the time it occurs to him that McCoy would know something about her, Thomas has already told him.  Shortly after he's in the process of burning his bridge with McCoy, in the same book, even as he pumps him for his information on his mother and Thomas.  McCoy even then only confirms and details what Thomas has already told him, and keeps further information secret.  It's not likely he simply would have spilled.
- A few Red Courts and the White King know who Margaret is, but this is not anywhere near knowable until well after they are already trying to kill Harry.

So that's all of his possible sources, and they are all pretty much duds until Thomas blows open his story.  If he did look into it, he would have gotten nowhere.  It's very possible he didn't, that he wrote off one demon's words as a way to manipulate him.

Comment: very thorough. The author did a good job drawing a lot of lines for Harry, and keeping readers in the dark (like mushroom :D)

Answer (score 1):

Well... I think, that one of the reasons is... well... he never knew her. I may have a biased point of view, but as a person, whose mother died during their childhood: You get used to it. Sure, if you knew the person, then there is a bit of trauma and sadness, but all in all you'll get used to it.

And Harry never knew his mother. I mean... why would you obsess about someone you never knew? Apart from becoming rather obsessed because of some kind of trauma, e.g.: bullying. You can't miss something you never had.

I also believe, that Harry is better this way. If you want to read about a PI who is obsessed about his missing mother, I recommend reading the Nightside series :) It's also quite funny.